# Windows Store App: how to programmatically launch bluetooth settings app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to port an app I built on Windows Phone 8 to a Windows Store App 8.1. One of the features I had on my mobile version was the ability for the user to "launch" the in-built Bluetooth settings app from code using:

```
ms-settings-bluetooth:
```

Is it possible to do this in a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to the same question. I thought I'd add the answer I found here. It seems that the URI is not supported on Windows store as suggested by the reserved URIs listed here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx

This has been answered elsewhere. It looks like you can only show the settings panel and not specifically Bluetooth.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a30564be-c91d-4ad4-a402-de1d2cd4f0cc/how-to-open-the-bluetooth-settings-panel-in-a-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp

Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.Show()

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Robin!